# Serialized objects in view state

Tags: asp.net, serialization, webforms, viewstate

Hi i have been going through the documentation of viewstate. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) It was mentioned that objects that can be serialized are stored in viewstate. What is the meaning of serializing of objects ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization is the process of turning an object into a stream of bytes that can be stored somewhere or sent across the wire.

Specifically in .NET, you can make a class serializable by adding the `[Serializable]` (C#) or `<Serializable>` (VB) attribute to the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is the process of taking an object in it's current state and turning into a "data" representation, most commonly in binary or xml formats.

For more information check out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization